# Is it possible to disable plugins defined in di.xml programatically?

Tags: magento2, plugin, dependency-injection, di, di.xml

Given a plugin defined in di.xml such as the following:

```
<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="se_catalog_product_plugin_ample"
            type="Example\Module\Model\Plugin\Catalog\Product"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false" />
</type>
```

How can I disable this defined plugin **programatically** (so not via di.xml but in code)? So when Magento comes round to processing the `se_catalog_product_plugin_ample` plugin, it is disabled, as if the node above had `disabled="true"`.

I need to be able to alter this plugin programatically due to the requirement of reacting to store config differing in seperate store views in use in the environment. This config can't be reacted upon in di.xml (as far as I know).

Not sure if this is even possible. I know it would be possible to add logic inside the plugin to just `$proceed()` based on whatever condition needed, but this is one module wanting to disable another that I don't want to have tightly coupled. i.e. the module `Example_Foo` wants to disable a plugin in `Example_Module`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like in this case you might have to make a preference on the plugin class, extend it with your class, then conditionally call the `parent`/original plugin method based on some system config you want to check.

I haven't tested this but seems like it might work unless preferences don't work as expected for the plugin/interceptor process.

#### preference in di.xml

```
<preference for="Example\Module\Model\Plugin\Catalog\Product" type="Your\Module\Model\ConditionalProductPlugin"/>
```

#### preference class

```
namespace Your\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class ConditionalProductPlugin extends \Example\Module\Model\Plugin\Catalog\Product
{
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        $originalClassArg1,
        $originalClassArg2,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        parent::__construct($originalClassArg1, $originalClassArg2);
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Check config for some flag to determine if original plugins should run
     */
    public function isDisabled()
    {
        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

        return $this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            'some/config/path/disabled',
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $store
        );
    }

    /**
     * Example for before plugin
     */
    public function beforeSomething($subject, ...$args)
    {
        if ($this->isDisabled()) {
            return null;
        }

        // Allow the calling of the original before plugin
        return parent::beforeSomething($subject, ...$args);
    }

    /**
     * Example for around plugin
     */
    public function aroundSomething($subject, $proceed, ...$args)
    {
        if ($this->isDisabled()) {
            return $proceed(...$args);
        }

        // Allow the calling of the original around plugin
        return parent::aroundSomething($subject, $proceed, ...$args);
    }

    /**
     * Example for after plugin
     */
    public function afterSomething($subject, $result, ...$args)
    {
        if ($this->isDisabled()) {
            return $result;
        }

        // Allow the calling of the original after plugin
        return parent::afterSomething($subject, $result, ...$args);
    }
}
```

Comment: After coming back to this some years later, I believe this is the only feasable approach, agreed!

Answer (score 34):

In your `di.xml` you can do the following:

```
<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="se_catalog_product_plugin_ample" disabled="true" />
</type>
```

Magento does it out of the box in `Magento/Backend/etc/adminhtml/di.xml` with the following :

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action">
    <plugin name="storeCheck" disabled="true" />
</type>
```

Side note: you may have to make your module depends on the `Example\Module` ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Raphael, appeciate it. I need to be able to do this programatically though, rather than altering the `disabled` attribute in the di.xml of the other module from the disabler module. I'm going to need to disable the plugin based on system config differing per store. Your answer is actually what I'm doing right now in the wild and does work, but it's a stop gap as in the future I'll need the programatic approach.

Comment: Useful tip: you can check all possible plugin XML attributes in XSD schema: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/0c786907ffe03d0e2990612eec16ee58b00379c5/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd#L162-L167

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can be a good idea but you can write an around plugin to that plugin and stop the call. Do at your own risk. Magento recommends avoid around plugins. But seems this can be a perfect purpose.

```
<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
    <plugin name="se_catalog_product_plugin_ample"
            type="Example\Module\Model\Plugin\Catalog\Product"
            sortOrder="10"
            disabled="false" />
</type>
```

So lets suppose, In `Example\Module\Model\Plugin\Catalog\Product` this file there is a function define which is like `beforeDelete`(its an actual function in product model which cleans cache..just take it as demo). Now write a new plugin `aroundBeforeDelete`.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function aroundBeforeDelete(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
    ) {

        $this->request->getControllerName();
        // set your condition here or whatever your code
        if($this->request->getControllerName() != 'whatever'){
            $result = $proceed();
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The original method (in this example `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::delete`) would never execute so you can't use this to skip just one plugin - only all plugins and the original functionality