# Klavio Vendor File Override on Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2

Hi guys I want to override klavio php file. My main purpose is make it checkbox default as checked. Now is default False.

Current File:
vendor>klavio>magento2-extention>Plugin>CheckoutLayoutPlugin.php

How can I Override This file on magento 2.3.3

```
<?php


namespace Klaviyo\Reclaim\Plugin;

use Klaviyo\Reclaim\Helper\ScopeSetting;


class CheckoutLayoutPlugin
{
    public function __construct(
        ScopeSetting $klaviyoScopeSetting
    ) {
        $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting = $klaviyoScopeSetting;
    }

    public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $processor, $jsLayout)
    {
        if ($this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSIsActive())
        {
            $smsConsentCheckbox = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox',
                    'options' => [],
                    'id' => 'kl_sms_consent',
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.kl_sms_consent',
                'label' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSConsentLabelText(),
                'description' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSConsentText(),
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'checked' => false,
                'validation' => [],
                'sortOrder' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutSMSConsentSortOrder(),
                'id' => 'kl_sms_consent',
            ];

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['kl_sms_consent'] = $smsConsentCheckbox;
        }
        // Open to ideas here, since we don't overwrite the customer-email section
        // we need to distinguish if the customer is logged in or not, object manager is an easy way to do so
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

        if (!$customerSession->isLoggedIn() && $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutEmailIsActive())
        {
            $emailConsentCheckbox = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/checkbox',
                    'options' => [],
                    'id' => 'kl_email_consent',
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.kl_email_consent',
                'description' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutEmailText(),
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'checked' => false, <<<<<<------ I WANT TO CHANGE HERE AS LIKE "TRUE"
                'validation' => [],
                'sortOrder' => $this->_klaviyoScopeSetting->getConsentAtCheckoutEmailSortOrder(),
                'id' => 'kl_email_consent',
            ];

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['kl_email_consent'] = $emailConsentCheckbox;
        }


        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Same other topic but not resolved

[Klaviyo Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/350835/klaviyo-magento-2)

Comment: I have answered the other question

Comment: You should disable it in your custom module di,xml file.

ex : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146310/is-it-possible-to-disable-plugins-defined-in-di-xml-programatically

And rewrite di.xml file in same module or new module

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using preference in Your Custom Module.

Use it like in di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> <preference for="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\CheckoutLayoutPlugin" type="MyCompany\ModuleName\Plugin\CheckoutLayOutPlugin" /> </config>
```